# OSX dock mysterious element

Tags: macos, dock

I have a mysterious element appearing on my dock that looks like the indicator under a folder but isn't actually attached to anything - any ideas how to get rid of this?

[image: Screenshot of my dock]

If I turn on dock hiding it disappears when the dock is hidden but reappears when the dock is visible.

Hardware: Macbook Pro Retina 13 running OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: It's the downloading indicator [thermometer], should fill from left to right as a download completes, but it seems to get stuck in Yosemite. Yours don't even look like it properly belongs to the app above it. You found the fix, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by restarting the dock by running the following in the terminal:

```
killall -KILL Dock
```